# how to achieve single sign on in java for google apps

Tags: java, google-app-engine, single-sign-on

I am new to java also at Google Apps, I am using Eclipse.

I want to create a simple app that perform SSO in java with google.

i have done the demo app that will host over google app engine, it is working fine using 
 [google plugin](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html)
how can i do it with my app running on my server.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [GAE: Configuring Your App's Authentication](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/auth.html) article. After configuring it you can check user using [The Users Java API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/) invoking:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

This is the simplest way. There are many other. Like using OpenID described here: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-book/wiki/Authentication

You can also create your own auth servlet filter wchich redirects users to `userService.createLoginURL` URL if needed.

Comment: I have implemented it, app is running on my http://localhost:18359/, but on deploying it over google market places, when i run it, instead of asking gmail credentials, it just give a fake login form and login me.

Comment: Did you configured your app as described here http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/auth.html ? You can also add you own filter and redirect user to `userService.createLoginURL`. AFAIK GAE production has no fake login form - It may be generated by your framework.

Comment: You are right, GAE has no fake login, as i said, I didn't deployed app over GAE, I have my app running on my server http://localhost:18359/, I have just given this url in Application Manifest,                               <Extension id="navLink" type="link">
    <Name>SSO custom app</Name>
    <Url>http://localhost:18359/</Url>
</Extension>                                                               so I don't need to configure all stuff in     http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/auth.html

Comment: I have check when I am running my app on my server in sign in url

***claimid=www.google.com/accounts/o8/id***

is missing, some body know how i add it with sign in url that is auto generated by userService.createLoginURL

Comment: GAE dev enviroment shows fake auth dialog and `userService.createLoginURL` creates url to this dialog. **If you deploy the same app on production (and configure the prod env auth) you will get login dialog to google account.** Sou you still want to implement SSO on dev server?